# Agregar clase al seleccionar un elemento padre y quitarle al dar click al elemento hijo

Tags: javascript, jquery, script

necesito saber si es posible hacer esto.

1. Al dar click en la clase `langs-menu` agregarle una clase active a los li con clase `language` es decir quedaria de esta manera `<li class="language active">...</li>`
2. Al dar click algun elemento li con clase language remover todas las clases active es decir quedaría en el estado original.

muestra de codigo:

```
<ul class="langs-menu">
 <li class="language">..</li>
 <li class="language">..</li>
<ul>
```

Comment: Que yo sepa el elemento `<ul>` de por si no tiene contenido, es un padre de elementos `<li>`, a menos que lo escribas mal en plan `<ul>texto<li>linea</li><li>linea</li></ul>` y entonces puedas hacer clic sobre `texto`, pero en una sintaxis formal eso no deberia ser asi, solo podrias hacer clic sobre los hijos, que a su vez podrian pasarle el evento al padre `<ul>` pero claro, podrian entrar en conflicto si son todos de clase `language`. Poner una linea sin esa clase para que haga lo que pides en las demas seria una solución, pero no se si eso te sirve. Pon esa clase `langs-menu` en un boton.

Comment: @masterguru encontre la solución.. era el metodo stopPropagation que hace que no selecciona al padre. deje la respuesta abajo.

Comment: Ya veo, bueno, no se aprecia demasiado bien donde hacer clic para que coja el <ul> pero vale, funciona.  Por eso decia lo del boton, es más claro para que sirve. Seguramente tu pintas la lista o la enmarcas de algun modo y te da igual, pero a pelo esto es lo que se ve: https://jsfiddle.net/9jbm80kL/, y no parece demasiado intuitivo hacer clic en un espacio en blanco.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la respuesta en stackoverflow en ingles.

```
    $('.langs-menu').click(function() {
     $('li.language').each(function(){
          $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    });
    $('li.language').click(function(e) {
      $('li.language').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
      });
       e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

lo dejo por si a alguien le interesa <3!